# Renaming Header in Dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, multiple-columns, rename

I have a provided dataset and I would like to know if the column dataset can be renamed easily. Or would there be code changes to do so? Any advice on how to go about this?

Three datasets have the same naming convention for the datasets. Hence I would like to rename it.

Comment: If they have same naming convention sometimes it's easier to stack them using APPEND and then transpose if required a wide structure.

Comment: Are you asking how to rename the variables in the dataset? Or do you want to modify the labels attached to the variables?  I lot of PROC's will use the labels instead of the names as the report headers in their printed results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`proc datasets` is the Swiss-army knife of dataset tools in SAS. You can rename datasets and columns with it.

Renaming datasets in the WORK library:

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    change dataset1 = renamed_dataset1
           dataset2 = renamed_dataset2
           dataset3 = renamed_dataset3
    ;
quit;
```

Renaming columns in a dataset in the WORK library:

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    modify dataset1;
        rename column1 = renamed_column1
               column2 = renamed_column2
               column3 = renamed_column3
        ;
quit;
```

`proc datasets` is interactive in that it can support multiple operations at once. For example, you can do all of the above in one step.

```
proc datasets lib=work nolist;
    change dataset1 = renamed_dataset1
           dataset2 = renamed_dataset2
           dataset3 = renamed_dataset3
    ;

    modify renamed_dataset1;
        rename column1 = renamed_column1
               column2 = renamed_column2
               column3 = renamed_column3
        ;
quit;
```